# Displaying images on demand

Tags: html, css, google-api

I need to make sure that when I enter a request, I get pictures (in google). There is such a line of html code:

```
    <div>
        <form action="https://www.google.com/imghp">
            <input  type="text" name="q">
            <input type="submit" value="Google Image Search">
        </form>
    </div>
```

But when you enter a request, it simply throws it to the page with a request, where you need to PRESS the search button. Is there any way to make the pictures of my request appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Searching in **Google Images**, you can use this HTML code:

```html
<form method="GET" action="http://images.google.com/images">
   <input type="text" name="q">
   <input type="submit" value="Search Google Images">
</form>
```